# wget not working with raspberry pi project pacman in terminal

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, debian-jessie

I am trying to do the raspberry pi project [Pacman Treasure](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/pacman-terminal/3) and on the first step it says to use the command `wget -O - http://rpf.io/pacmanstart | bash` and when I tried, the terminal gave me an error saying that '0' was an invalid option. I double checked my command and tried again. It still didn't work. I used `wget --help` and used `man wget` but I didn't see any problem. Has anyone else had this problem? I am using Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be zero `0` = 0 but big `o` = `O` O. `wget -O -` not `wget -0 -`.
`O` like `Output`, `-O -` means wget should output downloaded files to stdout.

Comment: I didn't realize that  it was a 0

Comment: Sorry I mean I didn't realize that it was an O